# Allow symbolic links in wildfly

Tags: symlink, wildfly

i'm using wildfly 8.2.0 and kubuntu 14.04. If i create a symbolic link under the welcome-content folder i can not call it from browser.

Example:

$wildflyHome/welcome-content/test/index.html --> localhost:8080/test/index.html ==> works.

$wildflyHome/welcome-content/*symlink*/index.html --> localhost:8080/symlink/index.html ==> doesn't work.

"symlink" is the symbolic link which is created by

```
ln -s /path/to/symlink $wildflyHome/welcome-content
```

How can i access the content of a symbolic link?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: As described in this discussion [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/252510#_=_) there are currently no configuration option to allowing symbolic links. I created i ticket which you can find here [link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4382)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. I'm getting a `WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/iv-storage/imagens' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']` in my log. Have no ideia how to make this `follow-symlink` to true.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting the same problem. I'm getting a WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/iv-storage/imagens' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]'] in my log. Have no ideia how to make this follow-symlink to true.

You can set it in the file handler section of the undertow subsystem configuration:

In subsystem/server/host :

```
<location name="/your/web/path" handler="yourHandler"/>
```

In subsystem/handlers :

```
<file name="yourHandler" follow-symlink="true" path="/your/local/path"/>
```

See [Undertow subsystem configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Undertow+subsystem+configuration) for more details on this configuration file.

Comment: I can confirm that this still works with WildFly 26